# Main difference between OpenCL and OpenCL Embedded profile

Tags: opencl

Recently I was seeing OpenCL EP support on some development boards like odroid XU. One thing I know is that OpenCL EP is for ARM processors, but in what features will it vary from the main desktop based OpenCL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main differences are enumerated below (as of OpenCL 1.2):

- 64-bit integer support is optional.
- Support for 3D images is optional.
- Support for 2D image array writes is optional. If the `cles_khr_2d_image_array_writes`
  extension is supported by the embedded profile, writes to 2D image arrays are supported.
- There are some limitations on the available channel data types for images and image arrays (in particular, images with channel data types of `CL_FLOAT` and `CL_HALF_FLOAT` only support `CL_FILTER_NEAREST` sampler filter modes)
- There are limitations on the sampler addressing modes available to images and image arrays.
- There are some floating-point rounding changes that you may need to take into account.
- Floating-point addition, subtraction, and multiplication will always be correctly rounded, other operations such as division and square roots have varying accuracies. There are tons of other floating-point things to watch out for as well.
- Conversions between integer data types and floating point integers are limited in precision (but there are exceptions).

In short, the main differences here are in floating-point accuracy. In other words, the embedded profile need not adhere to the IEEE 754 floating-point specification, which may be a problem if you are doing lots of numerical calculations which rely on it. Quoted from the specification:

> This relaxation of the requirement to adhere to IEEE 754 requirements
>   for basic floating- point operations, though extremely undesirable, is
>   to provide flexibility for embedded devices that have lot stricter
>   requirements on hardware area budgets.

There is also something that is not mentioned in section 10 but is worth noting: while desktop profiles must have a compiler available to compile OpenCL kernels, embedded profiles need not provide one. This can be seen through the `clGetDeviceInfo` documentation, which states:

```
CL_DEVICE_COMPILER_AVAILABLE: Return type: cl_bool

Is CL_FALSE if the implementation does not have a compiler available
to compile the program source. Is CL_TRUE if the compiler is available.
This can be CL_FALSE for the embededed (sic) platform profile only.
```

---

For a complete and detailed list of the OpenCL Embedded Profile specification, fire up your PDF reader, download the OpenCL spec (whichever version you are developing for), and find the relevant section.

Comment: Interesting, does this mean, the result of neural network written in opencl 1.1 may not produce right output?

Answer (score 2):

The section 10 in the standard answers your question. This section is entirely dedicated to the OCL embedded profile, ans starts by enumerating the restriction that this profile implies.